# How to get round corner textbox using jquery without images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, rounded-corners

I try to get round corners for textbox. But how can i get it. Here is the class

```
.tbox
{
 float:left;
 width:200px;
 margin-top:10px;
 margin-left:10px;

}
```

when i call using jquery using

```
$('.tbox').corners("4px");
```

it is not working. I already included Jquery.js and jquery.corners.js. But its not working. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make a rounded corner div and inside that place a text box with no borders. I think this will be the easiest way to accomplish your need.

```
<script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.corner.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready ( function () {
        $("#div1").corner("round");
    });
</script>

<style>
#div1 { width: 200px; height: 30px; background-color: #a9a9a9; }
#txtBox { width: 180px; height: 20px; background-color: transparent; position: relative; top: 5px; left: 10px; border-style: none; }
</style>


<div id="div1">
    <input type="text" id="txtBox" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

You can add following class to the textbox for rounded corner:

```
class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"
```

Hope this would help you.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using pure CSS:

```
border-radius: 3px;
-moz-border-radius: 3px;
-webkit-border-radius: 3px;
```

However it won't work in IE, but I treat it as punishment for using this browser :D With next version it will work probably.

Comment: Better not to use -moz styles since it is not browser independent.

Comment: So you can treat is as a reward for using browser that sticks to web standards :P And -moz itself can be dangerous, but as you can see, I use 3 styles together to be safe.

Comment: These all are CSS3 specific and many browsers don't support this.

Comment: I really hate seeing these "pure css" crap. Using -moz or -webkit is not "pure" css. Its crap.

Comment: @rahul yes you can if it's IE < 7.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it easily with [DD_roundies](http://www.dillerdesign.com/experiment/DD_roundies/)

jQuery group suggested using it for rounding corners.

 
its the best i've seen.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that Arka Chatterjee suggested the best solution for using jquery to create rounded corners.  Just reference the files jquery-ui.css and jquery-ui.min.js then add the classes mentioned.  I would have voted for it, but I don't have enough "reputation" yet.  Here's an example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="txtBox" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a css rounded corners code with javascript. This one is quite simple and easy to edit. Works in all browsers

[check this link](http://woork.blogspot.com/2009/08/css3-rounded-corners-for-every-browser.html)

Note: The rounded corners for div's is working in all browsers including ie6, but the text box rounded corners is not working in ie6.

Answer (score 0):

Put the input inside a div, and set rounded corners on the div. Remove the input's own borders and padding and make it as big as the wrapper div (minus any padding you want on the div).

Answer (score 0):

Are you an experienced JavaScript programmer and can you handle the HTML5 Canvas element?

Then you can give jQuery Background Canvas a try. Inject one single canvas behind your form and draw rounded corners on your text box. Here is the plugin, and this site makes a vast use of it:
[jQuery Background Canvas Plugin](http://www.maierhofer.de/en/open-source/jquery-background-canvas-plugin.aspx)